# how connect to phpmyadmin from other hosts

Tags: permissions, phpmyadmin, wampserver

I have a lan network with 2 computer and installed wamp on computer 1.

now I want to access to whole of phpmyadmin on computer 1 from computer 2 and make changes.

from users tab in root of phpmyadmin page I created a user.
I filled username field with 'root' and host field with my computer 2 IP address and left password field with "no password" and checked all Global privileges for my user.

now I connect to wamp on computer 1 from computer 2 and click on phpmyadmin link.
but It give me this error:

> **FORBIDDEN**
>
> you don't have permission to access /phpmyadmin/ on this server

what I must do now for solving this problem?

Comment: This question has been answered on:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/28715804/2633707

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That error message has more to do with Apache blocking access, than with phpMyAdmin, or the MySQL user account created.

Your issue is with Apache's configuration, or more specifically your WAMP's configuration of the /phpmyadmin URL.

Find the configuration file where the \phpmyadmin URL Alias is set up. It possibly will have these lines in it -

```
<Location /phpmyadmin>
  order deny,allow
  deny from all
  allow from 127.0.0.1
</Location>
```

Add another `allow from IP.Address` line in it to match the IP.Address of your other LAN system. Restart Apache.

If phpMyAdmin is not set up via an Alias (it is under WampDeveloper, not sure about other WAMPs like Xampp or WampServer), but is rather just a dump of its files in a DocumentRoot (website's webroot) sub-folder, check the .htaccess file there.

> I filled username field with 'root' and host field with my computer 2 IP address and left password field with "no password" and checked all Global privileges for my user.

In this case, the `host` field will always be in relation to the location of MySQL, not to the system  phpMyAdmin is being accessed from... If you are accessing MySQL via phpMyAdmin, the `host` field should always be - `localhost`. As phpMyAdmin is on the same system MySQL is. The only time you'd use another domain-name, host-name, or IP for host: is when you are accessing MySQL **directly** from another system. By directly I mean, not via a script or URL, but via some type of a client (which is almost always a binary/executable).

Comment: Config file is in C:\wamp\alias\phpmyadmin.conf  That is the file you should change as per rightstuffs answer. Add a line >  allow from Computer2's ip address

Answer (score 11):

change below line in C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-xampp.conf, you can directly open this file by 
[image]

```
<Directory "C:/xampp/phpMyAdmin">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride all
    Require all granted
    ErrorDocument 403 /error/XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 2):

go to PHPMYADMIN.conf or search on it from wamp or wamp64

adjust on it as the following:

change

```
Require local
```

to be

```
Require all granted
```

And add your another client IP address after this line

```
Allow from localhost ::1 127.0.0.1
```

add this

```
Allow from CLIENTIPADDRESS
```

Restart Wamp or Wamp64

Answer (score 0):

> Note: this is for development purposes and should not be done in a production environment!

Go to `C:\wamp\alias\phpmyAdmin.conf`, open `phpmyadmin.conf` in Notepad, add the following:

```
<Directory "c:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin3.3.9/">
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
  AllowOverride all
  Order Allow,Deny
  Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Change here is allow from all only..

Comment: Does 'Allow from all' really mean 'allow any host to administer this'?  If so, it hardly seems like a good idea.

Comment: yes but for development purpose u can use it. not for real world sceneario.

Comment: For real world u can add ip address there allow from 192.168.X.X

Comment: That information should be in the answer and not left unmentioned.  It is crucial to know that your suggested solution is dangerous to the security of the system. And it would be good to have some indication of how the entry should look after you've got it running.

Comment: thax will consider in future :)

Answer (score -2):

First just check you have installed php, mysql and apache correctly.
Now if are you able to access phpmyadmin from your local host then above things are installed correctly. If you want to access phpmyadmin from another host, make the entry of 2nd host in following config file 
`/etc/httpd/config.d/phpmyadmin.conf`

```
<Location /phpmyadmin>  
order deny,allow  
deny from all   
allow from 127.0.0.1 <2nd host IP address>
</Location>
```

Then save you httpd settings and stop

```
service httpd restart
```

And now you are able to access phpmyadmin from another host